# Adobe Illustrator: How to make turnaround character

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, adobe-after-effects

Good day. I'm learning after effects animation right now. I'm a software developer. And i can't draw.

So i'm using free AI from freepik.

This is the template i'm following which i asked a friend to draw(i paid it)

[image]

Is there a tutorial how to create an image like that if the image i downloaded is something like this?

[image]

Like in adobe illustrator Object>Transform>Rotate

I can ask someone to draw the image but i don't have much fund right now and I'm still learning. So i'm trying to make things work of what i have right now.

Thank you so much.

Comment: This is not possible in Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott ofcourse it is. Anyway the workflow is same as the one on this video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yvUkaBhwAFY

Comment: @joojaa of *course* you can *draw* the poses... but this question seems to be seeking some form of automation.. which is not possible in Illustrator.

Comment: Yes but even with kickass automation (which in this case exists by the way) its not really possible to do it any faster than drawing it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have a flat image. It doesn't contain 3D information for other views.  You would need a 3D model to get other views automatically (=rotate).

In theory an Artificial Intelligence application who knows enough of our world could guess which 3D shape fits into your flat image, but I haven't seen such program for sale. Knowing our world means in this case understanding all usual body forms and clothes - artificial human reasoning. In pure math infinitely many 3D shapes have the same front view, but other views can be something unwanted, like this:

[image]

Without that AI software someone must create the 3D model or the needed flat views for your animation. Both of these options need a skilled person who has already developed his workflow to handle the case. A beginner would need a day even for drawing a good copy of your image, creating a plausible set of still nonexistent views would take weeks or months. Sorry.

Comment: Grilli kuumaksi